# Function to wrap html snippet in a div/span element in web-mode

Tags: html, web-mode

I have a html snippet like this:

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>jasmine</li>
    <li>cinthia</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

How to wrap the ul element (after selection) inside a div element in web-mode like this,

```
<body>
  <div>   <!--- inserted via function --->
    <ul>   
      <li>jasmine</li>
      <li>cinthia</li>
    </ul>
  </div>   <!--- inserted via function --->
</body>
```

I use web-mode for html files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `M-x web-mode-element-wrap`